# Critique my proof of: For every real number x, if $x^2 \geq x$, then either $x \leq 0 \lor x \geq 1$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Critique my proof on correctness, structure, etc.

*Proof.* Suppose that $x^2 \geq x.$ Assume for the sake of contradiction that $x > 0$ and $x < 1$. It follows that $x^2 < x$, so it cannot be the case that $x^2 \geq x$ and that is a contradiction. Therefore, it must be the case that for every real number $x$, if $x^2 \geq x$, then either $x \leq 0 \lor x \geq 1$.

My concern with the proof is the statement "It follows that $x^2 < x$". Is it okay to assume this in a proof or does it need to be proven?

Comment: It isn’t okay to assume $x^2<x$ in this problem since that is exactly what you’re trying to “prove”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps give more information why is it so.

Since $x>0$, multiplying to an inequality doesn't change the sign.

Hence we can multiply positive $x$ to $x<1$ and conclude that $x^2 < x$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof sounds good.

If you are interested in another way to tackle this problem, you can do it as follows:
\begin{align*}
x^{2} \geq x & \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - x \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x^{2} - x + \frac{1}{4}\right) - \frac{1}{4} \geq 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} \geq \frac{1}{4}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left|x - \frac{1}{2}\right| \geq \frac{1}{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\leq 0)\vee(x \geq 1)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: How did you go from... $$\iff (x^2 - x + \frac{1}{4}) - \frac{1}{4} \geq 0$$ to $$\iff (x - \frac{1}{2})^2 \geq \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: I completed the square. Precisely, I applied the following identity:

$$(a - b)^{2} = a^{2} - 2ab +  b^{2}$$

At the given case, $a = x$ and $b = 1/2$.